# Locating the File Responsible for Reading and Interpreting Command Line Elements in the Bash Shell

Tags: bash, gnu

I have a question regarding the Bash shell. I'm currently
working on an exercise that involves building a basic shell. I understand that
properly reading and interpreting each element of the command line is crucial,
especially when dealing with special symbols like redirection or pipes. Out of
curiosity, I wanted to find the specific file in the Bash shell that handles
this functionality, but I'm having trouble locating it. Could you provide any
hints or guidance on finding it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Clone [the bash repo](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/bash.git) and look at `parse.y`.
You can also go to the much more comfortable but less reliable [unofficial mirror](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/parse.y).

Comment: Thanks Uberhumus. I've download the repo and I'm looking at the file. Can't believe it.